# How to check HTML code in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby

I want to check a line of HTML with a ruby script. Specifically I want to tell the status of local mountain biking trails. When the trails are closed, website displays [this](http://usnwc.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/trailsclosed.png) image:
[image: Trails closed image.]

When the trails are open, [this](http://usnwc.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/trailsopen.png) image:

[image: Trails open image.]

Code from the website ([usnwc.org](http://usnwc.org/)):

```
<div id="trail-status" class="widget widget_tcstatus">      
    <div class="tcwstatus">
        <div class='trails-current'>
            <img src='/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/trailsclosed.png' alt=' Image not found'/>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

I could check to see which image is being displayed to return the status. Is there a way to accomplish this in Ruby? Possibly using `Net::HTTP`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `open-uri` and `regexp` like below:

```
require 'open-uri'
content = open('http://urltopage.com/trail-path').read

if content =~ /trailsclosed\.png/
  puts "Trails closed!"
elsif content =~ /trailsopened\.png/
  puts "Trails opened!"
else
  puts "Oops, images not found?" 
end
```

Comment: Where `http://urltopage.com/trail_path` would be `http://usnwc.org/#trail-status`?

Comment: Yes, I just tested it here, and it got it the way you expected - just be aware that you are going to read the full page body and rely in an image name for identifying the trails state. I would send an warning in the `else` block - to let me know that the page changed and the images were not found.

Comment: Perfect. This works great. Could you show me what you mean by sending a warning in the `else` block in your answer?

Comment: @atwalsh04 sorry about the late answer, but I was talking about some kind of notification, so you would be informed that the HTML page might have changed and that you need to check for a different image now.